# Fancybox not firing

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am creating a simple gallery and fancybox does not seem to be firing and I have no idea why, I've used it before on other sites and works ok:

doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

script, css calls and js - script sources ok checked

```
<link href="../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../js/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("a[rel=gallery]").fancybox({
            'autoScale' : true,
            'transitionIn' : 'fade',
            'transitionOut' : 'fade'
                }
            });

        });
</script>
```

and the php i'm using to generate the thumbs from folder and also the href to call fancybox

```
$files = glob("../gallery/gallery/*.*"); 

for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) 
{
 $num = $files[$i]; echo '<a class="fancybox" rel=gallery href="'.$num.'">
 <img src="'.$num.'" class="gallery_img" alt="random image"></a>'; 
 }
```

this is the rendered html from the actual page:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="../gallery/gallery/cat.jpg">
<img src="../gallery/gallery/cat.jpg" class="gallery_img" alt="random image">
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="../gallery/gallery/flypike.jpg">
<img src="../gallery/gallery/flypike.jpg" class="gallery_img" alt="random image">
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="../gallery/gallery/zandrb.jpg">
<img src="../gallery/gallery/zandrb.jpg" class="gallery_img" alt="random image"></a>
```

Comment: you have a typo on rel attribute, the value is not quoted. Anyway could you post a snippet of the rendered html? Do you get any error on the JS console?

Comment: Do any errors pop up on firebug/chrome debugger etc??

Comment: @Umair thanks, the console found the syntax error

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Complete syntax error found by console, many thanks for suggestion, never used that before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("a[rel=gallery]").fancybox({
        'autoScale' : true,
        'transitionIn' : 'fade',
        'transitionOut' : 'fade'
            } // shouldn't be there
        });

    }); // shouldn't be there
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `}` after `'transitionOut' : 'fade'`